# Is there a good C# design pattern for parsing strings that when split have different amounts of data?

Tags: c#, parsing, types, design-patterns

I am dealing with values delimited by commas sent to me as a string. The strings come in many different structures (meaning different data types in different locations of the string as well as varying amounts of data). So while one string might be represented as:

**- common data,identifier,int,string,string,string.**

Another might be represented as:

**- common data,identifier,int,int,string,string,string.**

Design goals:

- Common parse method
- Common validation (i.e. int.TryParse() returns true)
- Readily able to add different structures

Is there a good design pattern, or combination of design patterns, that allows me to parse the values, check them, and return an object only if the right amount of values were pulled in and those values were the expected data types?

**Note:** I am dealing with more than 30 different string structures.

Comment: I would use regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the lines start with `common data, identifier`, and then are followed by a variable but expected (i.e. known based on the identifier) set of values, then a table approach could work well.  To continue your example, say you have two different types:

- common data,identifier,int,string,string,string.
- common data,identifier,int,int,string,string,string.

You can build a class that defines what you're looking for:

```
class ItemDesc
{
    public string Ident { get; private set; }
    public string Fields { get; private set; }
    public ItemDesc(string id, string flds)
    {
        Ident = id;
        Fields = flds;
    }
}
```

The `Fields` property is just a string that contains one-character type descriptions for the variable data.  That is, "isss" would be interpreted as `int,string,string,string`.

You can then build a `Dictionary<string, ItemDesc>` that you can use to look these up:

```
Dictionary<string, ItemDesc> ItemLookup = new Dictionary<string, ItemDesc>
{
    { "ItemType1", new ItemDesc("ItemType1", "isss") },
    { "ItemType2", new ItemDesc("ItemType2", "iisss") },
};
```

Now when you read a line, use `string.Split()` to split it into fields.  Get the identifier, look it up the dictionary to get the item descriptions, and then parse the rest of the fields.  Something like:

```
string line = GetLine();
var fields = line.Split(',');
// somehow get the identifier
string id = GetIdentifier();
ItemDesc desc;
if (!ItemLookup.TryGetValue(id, out desc))
{
    // unrecognized identifier
}
else
{
    int fieldNo = 3; // or whatever field is after the identifier
    foreach (var c in desc.Fields)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'i' :
               // try to parse an int and save it.
               break;
            case 's' :
               // save the string
               break;
            default:
               // error, unknown field type
               break;
         }
         ++fieldNo;
    }
}
// at this point if no errors occurred, then you have a collection
// of parsed fields that you saved.  You can now create your object.
```

Comment: Thanks. This will do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

would need little more details, based on your problem domain it could entirely change. but following seem to be the first set of patterns, they are ordered on suitability.

- [Interpreter](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternInterpreter.aspx)
- [Strategy](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx)
- [Builder](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBuilder.aspx)

Comment: These are all a very good start, thank you. Can you think of any details that would help narrow the selections down? I am able to determine the structure of the string based on an identifier within the string. Original post will be edited to show this.

Comment: 1. What is expected to change most? 2. How complex parsing each of these 30 different formats? 3. Are all these objects have some relation among them? etc. These are some of the questions that need to be answered before we can go to patterns. If you could edit your question on what are some of the design goals you're trying to achieve you could get to a good pattern which suits the solution.

Comment: 1. Everything after the common value and identifier changes the most, both in length and in format. 2. Parsing can be pretty easy. Just reading in the values. Validation at this point is simple. More in depth validation will be added in a different layer. 3. This relation question is a little abstract to me. They all share two common fields in the common value and identifier. Some have the same sequence of 5 values but they occur at different indexes of the string. I don't know what to look for here.

Comment: It looks like you dont need a pattern right now, probably you could refactor into patterns when your code grows, I'd say implement the simplest thing that solves your problem now. For relation I mean is there a parent-child, master-slave, or some kind of heirarchy exists in your objects.

Comment: I agree; a standard design pattern is probably not called for here.

Answer (score 1):

Just split them using [**`string.Split()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), and then [**`int.Parse()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) or [**`int.TryParse()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) each `int` value in the resulting array as needed.

```
var myStrings = string.Split(sourceString);
int myint1 = int.Parse(myStrings[0]);
```

Comment: I might suggest int.TryParse(), which will fail more gracefully, and allow you to determine which substrings are actually numbers.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on what design pattern to use to model these different string structures? I forgot to mention originally that they do all have two common data types at the beginning, one of which can uniquely identify the type of structure I need to parse. I will rephrase the question.

Comment: string.split is a bad idea.  Performance is poor, and it will fall down on common case where the data itself has a comma

Comment: @Joel: What would you suggest in place of string.split?

Comment: @7ogan - Your choice of Microsoft.VisualBasic.TextFieldParser or the FastCSV project over at CodeProject, and given your requirements probably the former.  Whatever you do with patterns to read the other objects, your _first_ responsibility here is to correctly read the csv data.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of dealing with this. Here's a simple one (outputting just an object array):

```
class Template
{
    // map identifiers to templates
    static Dictionary<string, string> templates = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "type1", "isss" },
        { "type2", "iisss" },
    };

    static bool ParseItem(string input, char type, out object output)
    {
        output = null;
        switch (type)
        {
            case 'i':
                int i;
                bool valid = int.TryParse(input, out i);
                output = i;
                return valid;
            case 's':
                output = input;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static object[] ParseString(string input)
    {
        string[] items = input.Split(',');
        // make sure we have enough items
        if (items.Length < 2)
            return null;
        object[] output = new object[items.Length - 2];
        string identifier = items[1];
        string template;
        // make sure a valid identifier was specified
        if (!templates.TryGetValue(identifier, out template))
            return null;
        // make sure we have the right amount of data
        if (template.Length != output.Length)
            return null;
        // parse each item
        for (int i = 0; i < template.Length; i++)
            if (!ParseItem(items[i + 2], template[i], out output[i]))
                return null;
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's amazing. We came up with almost identical solutions at almost the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in returning actual objects instead of just object arrays, you can put metadata into the class definitions of the objects you're returning. Then when you get the object type you look for the metadata to figure out where to find its value in the input array. Here's a quick example:

```
namespace Parser
{
    // create metadata attribute
    class CsvPositionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public CsvPositionAttribute(int position)
        {
            Position = position;
        }
    }

    // define some classes that use our metadata
    public class type1
    {
        [CsvPosition(0)]
        public int int1;
        [CsvPosition(1)]
        public string str1;
        [CsvPosition(2)]
        public string str2;
        [CsvPosition(3)]
        public string str3;
    }

    public class type2
    {
        [CsvPosition(0)]
        public int int1;
        [CsvPosition(1)]
        public int int2;
        [CsvPosition(2)]
        public string str1;
        [CsvPosition(3)]
        public string str2;
        [CsvPosition(4)]
        public string str3;
    }

    public class CsvParser
    {
        public static object ParseString(string input)
        {
            string[] items = input.Split(',');
            // make sure we have enough items
            if (items.Length < 2)
                return null;
            string identifier = items[1];
            // assume that our identifiers refer to a type in our namespace
            Type type = Type.GetType("Parser." + identifier, false);
            if (type == null)
                return null;
            object output = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            // iterate over fields in the type -- you may want to use properties
            foreach (var field in type.GetFields())
                // find the members that have our position attribute
                foreach (CsvPositionAttribute attr in
                    field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CsvPositionAttribute),
                                              false))
                    // if the item exists, convert it to the type of the field
                    if (attr.Position + 2 >= items.Length)
                        return null;
                    else
                        // ChangeType may throw exceptions on failure;
                        // catch them and return an error
                        try { field.SetValue(output,
                            Convert.ChangeType(items[attr.Position + 2],
                                               field.FieldType));
                        } catch { return null; }
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would require Reflection, correct? Is there any drastic performance cost here?

Comment: @7ogan: Yes, it uses reflection. I'm going to say that it will take maybe 50 microseconds to parse a string and create an instance. If that's too slow, you can speed things up by compiling some lambdas to do the manipulation.